# overriding envers auditing functionality

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I would like to override the auditing behavior of Hibernate Envers. I do not want audit records to be written into db for every change on the Entity. Instead, I want hibernate to write to a custom table with only four columns. Who made the change, what column in which table did they change (eg Address.line1), old value and previous value. All of them are varchars and possibly other details like when this change occurred. I should mention that we are using Spring-boot and data-jpa. I have looked into conditional auditing, but they only allow you to conditionally insert into the audit tables for each entity. I don't want the audit tables to be created at all

Best,
Prasana

Comment: and what is the difference with envers, you still have an auditing table but now you have a single one for all your entities. If you don't want envers then don't use envers, write your own entity listeners then.

Comment: We want the envers repositories and it's functionality

Comment: Which depend on the way the records are written, if you change that those won't work. Also envers itself doesn't provide repositories unless you are using the spring-data-envers project.

Comment: Currently we see indeed using spring data envers. My manager feels taking a snapshot of the entire entity at revision is a waste of space and wants this functionality in separate tables recorded as strings. We only need what was changed. Not what was not changed

Comment: Envers can do a lot more then what you use it for, either use it or write something yourself. Also why would it be a waste of space, for the development effort you need to write your own implementation and shoehorn Envers into that you can buy lots of storage...